# When I am running the consumer script in kafka I am getting the error 1 partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

This is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:latest'
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
  kafka:
    image: bitnami/kafka:latest
    depends_on:
    - zookeeper
    ports:
    - 9092:9092
    environment:
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=localhost
      - KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      - KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS=kafkatutorial:1:1
```

20/11/01 17:11:33 WARN NetworkClient: [Producer clientId=producer-1] 1 partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener, including [kafkatutorial-0]

Comment: Please create a new post rather than overwrite it

Answer (score -1):

The bitnami containers don't support `KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS` variable, only wurstmeister

You need to create your topics manually

Comment: Still getting the same error when running the command kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic kafkatutorial --from-beginning

Comment: Your `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` don't include localhost

Comment: If you exec into the container, that command would work fine, too

Comment: Ref https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-kafka#accessing-kafka-with-internal-and-external-clients